# MySQL protocol send show query,return table dose't exists

Tags: mysql

I try to send the mysql a query packet, show command always failed because table not exists. e.g.

`show tables` response with an error `#42S02Table 'test.table_names' doesn't exist`

```
T 127.0.0.1:54432 -> 127.0.0.1:3306 [AP]
  0c 00 00 00 03 73 68 6f    77 20 74 61 62 6c 65 73    .....show tables

T 127.0.0.1:3306 -> 127.0.0.1:54432 [AP]
  2f 00 00 01 ff 7a 04 23    34 32 53 30 32 54 61 62    /....z.#42S02Tab
  6c 65 20 27 74 65 73 74    2e 74 61 62 6c 65 5f 6e    le 'test.table_n
  61 6d 65 73 27 20 64 6f    65 73 6e 27 74 20 65 78    ames' doesn't ex
  69 73 74                                              ist
```

`show databases` response with an error `#42S02Table 'test.schemata' doesn't exist`

```
T 127.0.0.1:53904 -> 127.0.0.1:3306 [AP]
  0f 00 00 00 03 73 68 6f    77 20 64 61 74 61 62 61    .....show databa
  73 65 73                                              ses

T 127.0.0.1:3306 -> 127.0.0.1:53904 [AP]
  2c 00 00 01 ff 7a 04 23    34 32 53 30 32 54 61 62    ,....z.#42S02Tab
  6c 65 20 27 74 65 73 74    2e 73 63 68 65 6d 61 74    le 'test.schemat
  61 27 20 64 6f 65 73 6e    27 74 20 65 78 69 73 74    a' doesn't exist
```

But I use the command line to send a query, It's return ok,I compare the packet, it's same.

BTW, I use my program send `select @@version_comment`,'select * from test.test', it's response normally.

**EDIT**

`show grants` shows the privileges is ok for current user.

```
T 127.0.0.1:56636 -> 127.0.0.1:3306 [AP]
  0c 00 00 00 03 73 68 6f    77 20 67 72 61 6e 74 73    .....show grants

T 127.0.0.1:3306 -> 127.0.0.1:56636 [AP]
  01 00 00 01 01 2f 00 00    02 03 64 65 66 00 00 00    ...../....def...
  19 47 72 61 6e 74 73 20    66 6f 72 20 72 6f 6f 74    .Grants for root
  40 6c 6f 63 61 6c 68 6f    73 74 00 0c 21 00 00 0c    @localhost..!...
  00 00 fd 01 00 1f 00 00    05 00 00 03 fe 00 00 02    ................
  00 44 00 00 04 43 47 52    41 4e 54 20 41 4c 4c 20    .D...CGRANT ALL
  50 52 49 56 49 4c 45 47    45 53 20 4f 4e 20 2a 2e    PRIVILEGES ON *.
  2a 20 54 4f 20 27 72 6f    6f 74 27 40 27 6c 6f 63    * TO 'root'@'loc
  61 6c 68 6f 73 74 27 20    57 49 54 48 20 47 52 41    alhost' WITH GRA
  4e 54 20 4f 50 54 49 4f    4e 3e 00 00 05 3d 47 52    NT OPTION>...=GR
  41 4e 54 20 50 52 4f 58    59 20 4f 4e 20 27 27 40    ANT PROXY ON ''@
  27 25 27 20 54 4f 20 27    72 6f 6f 74 27 40 27 6c    '%' TO 'root'@'l
  6f 63 61 6c 68 6f 73 74    27 20 57 49 54 48 20 47    ocalhost' WITH G
  52 41 4e 54 20 4f 50 54    49 4f 4e 05 00 00 06 fe    RANT OPTION.....
  00 00 02 00                                           ....
```

Comment: Check if you have the permissions to execute the SQL query from outside the console.

Comment: Yes, I use the root user as same as the mysql cli.`mysql -uroot --protocol=tcp`

Comment: Compare the [users rights](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html)

Comment: I update my question, seems the rights is ok for current user